# Sharepoint 2010 out of box site Deployment from development to production

Tags: deployment

I developed sharepoint 2010 site with all OOB features(like document library, external list, SSRS reports, dashbaords) and designing using Sharepoint designer 2010.

Now I want to deploy all the stuff from development to production server. As I am not using visual studio for any purpose here.

One thing I can do is backup and restore(which is not recommended)
Please let me know the deployment process.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mechanisms for doing this, but doing a simple export from your dev environment and then an import into your prod environment is probably a good place to start.  You can move the whole site or just a list/library. You can do it via PowerShell or Central Admin:

Export: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx

Import: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428322.aspx

Comment: this is something backup and restore kind.. My concern is Once I move everything to production and do some changes in development.. how can I deploy those changes? And my site entirely related to SSRS reports, BCS and dashboard

Comment: You don't have to re-deploy the whole site with this method, although I can imagine it becoming increasingly difficult to determine what has changed between interations.  You may want to look at 3rd party tools if you want finely-grained control over deployments...including auto-detection of dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But mine is a very simple site.. What kind of 3rd party tools.. Any feature deployment process I can do?

Comment: I understand that it's simple today, but it's my experience that as a site grows it becomes increasingly difficult to manage the deployment of just changes versus a complete site refresh...it's not uncommon for dependencies to be missed.  I'd also be concerned that you are deploying to production directly from dev and bypassing a test or staging environment...i.e. missing an opportunity to test your deployment methodology.

Comment: I am sorry.. I missed out the point. Definitely we will be moving to staging first. 
Is there any way we can do deploying process as we do in visual studio(solution/package deployment(activating features) ) same here for OOB sharepoint site.. 
I have never deployed the site and now I am resposible for that. I am afraid.
Please clarify few things.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can save your site as template:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-HA101782501.aspx#_Toc258332696

Look at limitations!
Then you can save wsp package locally:

http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2009/10/19/sharepoint-2010-site-exporting-as-wsp-solution-part-1.aspx

Then you can transfer and deploy your wsp file to production server.

I would recommend this approach for some very very simple scenarios.

Comment: Since I am using custom pagelayouts etc(publishing site) I cant save my site as template. Any other way I can build wsp solution.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Site templates are solution only for some limited customizations. Any 'serious' SharePoint development is done by using Visual Studio and its a whole new game. Designer is very powerful tool but only if you are working directly on production environment and in most scenarios this is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the content deployment feature.  Once configured this will "push" out changes from one site to another.  This is more complicated and prone to errors if not done correctly, but may be what you are looking for.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263428.aspx